# password validation won't allow spaces in php

Tags: php, validation

I have a password field in my application. I used parsley validation for that. But, there is no validation I gave other than a required field. So it allows all characters. However, I would like to sanitize the password and not allow users to add spaces. And if they tried, there should be an error message shown. The password field should contain at least 1 number.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require('../config.php'); 
if(!isset($_SESSION['can_access']) || $_SESSION['can_access'] !== true ) 
    header('Location: login.php'); 
ob_start(); 
global $DB, $USER; 
$id=$USER->id; 
$clientid=$_GET['id'];

$errorMessage  = '';
$successMessage = ''; 
if(isset($_SESSION['successMessage'])) 
    { 
        $successMessage = $_SESSION['successMessage']; 
        unset($_SESSION['successMessage']); 
    }
if(isset($_POST['register'])) { 
    $errors = array(); 
    $data = array(); 
    $chk_sql = "SELECT * FROM {user} u where username = ?"; 
    if (!empty($chk_sql) ) {
        $errorMessage='Username already taken';
    }
    if(!$chk_username = $DB->get_record_sql($chk_sql, array($_POST['username'])) ) 
        { 
            $insert_record = new stdClass(); 
            $insert_record->username = $_POST['username']; 
            $insert_record->firstname = $_POST['firstname']; 
            $insert_record->email = $_POST['email']; 
            $insert_record->password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT); 
            $insert_record->mnethostid = 1;
            $insert_record->confirmed = 1; 
            $insert_record->idnumber = 2;       
            $insert_record->maildisplay = $clientid; 
            //$insert_record->timecreated = date('Y-m-d'); 
            if( $result = $DB->insert_record('user', $insert_record) ) 
                { 
                    $_SESSION['successMessage'] = "record created successfully"; 
                    header('Location: clients.php'); 

                }
        }
}
?>
```

Here is my password button:

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback"> 
<input id="signupInputPassword" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" required class="form-control" > 
<span class="fa fa-lock form-control-feedback text-muted"></span> 
</div>
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where i have to add this line

Comment: Why don't you want to allow spaces? I'd strongly recommend reading around the subject of good security practice, for example [OWASP's Authentication Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: yes...but when i told the same thing to my manager..he told no we don't allow spaces he told like that..thats'y..

Comment: actually what happened here if i click on space button it taking as dots..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

$password = $_POST['password'];

if (preg_match('/\s/', $password)) {

    echo "password has whitespace";

} else {

    if (strlen($password) <= '8') {
        echo "Your Password Must Contain At Least 8 Characters!";
    } elseif (!preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $password)) {
        echo "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Number!";
    } elseif (!preg_match("#[A-Z]+#", $password)) {
        echo "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Capital Letter!";
    } elseif (!preg_match("#[a-z]+#", $password)) {
        echo "Your Password Must Contain At Least 1 Lowercase Letter!";
    }

    $errors  = array();
    $data    = array();
    $chk_sql = "SELECT * FROM {user} u where username = ?";
    if (!empty($chk_sql)) {
        $errorMessage = 'Username already taken';
    }
    if (!$chk_username = $DB->get_record_sql($chk_sql, array($_POST['username']))) {
        $insert_record              = new stdClass();
        $insert_record->username    = $_POST['username'];
        $insert_record->firstname   = $_POST['firstname'];
        $insert_record->email       = $_POST['email'];
        $insert_record->password    = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $insert_record->mnethostid  = 1;
        $insert_record->confirmed   = 1;
        $insert_record->idnumber    = 2;
        $insert_record->maildisplay = $clientid;
        //$insert_record->timecreated = date('Y-m-d');
        if ($result = $DB->insert_record('user', $insert_record)) {
            $_SESSION['successMessage'] = "record created successfully";
            header('Location: clients.php');

        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: ok..if i want to add one special number and one special character must how i have to add.with error message like if they didn't add number and special character  it has to throw error

Comment: okay. i am editing this answer with some password validation check it.

Comment: and i need word count restriction only 20

Comment: did you mean maximum 20 characters?

Comment: @MrProPop is it just `$_POST['password']  > 20` OR `strlen($_POST['password'] ) > 20` ?

Comment: @MrProPop ok..i will look at that

Comment: @AshishPatel strlen($_POST['password']) > 20 Just typo :P

Comment: For word counting, you should go to your form and in the password field add this -> maxlength="20". This won't be enough because it can be manipulated from the inspect element so have a PHP server validation like this. if(strlen($_POST['password']) > 20) { error } else { success }

Comment: @AshishPatel  it's not working properly..if i add elseif condiitons its not showing..it s working only for whitespaces..ramaining conditions are not working

Comment: @AshishPatel can you please tell me why..it's working only for if condition..its not working the coniditons which is in else

Comment: create a chat room.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155060/discussion-between-mahesh-and-user200

Comment: hi ashish i have onedoubt..can you please help me

Comment: Tell me @user200

Comment: hi ashish can you please tell me how to import excel file values in mysql database